# How to add posts using React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm working on an app that adds posts to a table. My code below doesn't work. It's giving me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null(…) for
>   function handleAddNew()

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
      this.state = {
        number:'1',
        name:'gogo',
        title:'',
        views:'10',
        likes:'22',
        date:'1.1.1111'
    };
  }
    addPost(title){
      this.state.title.push(title);
      this.setState({
        post: this.state.title
      });
  }
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <AddPost addNew={this.addPost} />
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <Thead/>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <Row number={this.state.number}
                        name={this.state.name}
                        title={this.state.title}
                        views={this.state.views}
                        likes={this.state.likes}
                        date={this.state.date}/>
                </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
class AddPost extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
      this.state = {
        newPost: ''
     }
     this.updateNewPost = this.updateNewPost.bind(this);
  }
  updateNewPost(e){
    this.setState({newPost: e.target.value});
  }
  handleAddNew(){
    this.props.addNew(this.state.newPost);
    this.setState({newPost: ''});
  }
  render(){
    return (
        <div>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.newPost} onChange={this.updateNewPost} />
          <button onClick={this.handleAddNew}> Add Post </button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
class Thead extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <tr>
            <td id='number'>ID</td>
            <td id='name'>User name</td>
            <td id='title'>Post title</td>
            <td id='views'>Views</td>
            <td id='likes'>Likes</td>
            <td id='date'>Created at</td>
        </tr>
      );
   }
}
class Row extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <tr>
            <td>{this.props.number}</td>
            <td>{this.props.name}</td>
            <td>{this.props.title}</td>
            <td>{this.props.views}</td>
            <td>{this.props.likes}</td>
            <td>{this.props.date}</td>
        </tr>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't bind `handleAddNew` to `this` you need to add

`this.handleAddNew = this.handleAddNew.bind(this);`

in your constructor

if you are using babel and have `stage-2` plugin you can change your instance methods to arrow functions like so:

```
handleAddNew = () => {    
  // do stuff
}
```

instead of having to bind it in the constructor. The first method will work out of the box but if you are using babel it is definitely cleaner to do the second method.

Comment: Thanks it's working when I add bind. But there is next problem, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined(…). It doesn't read this.state.title.push(title); I thought that it would push the value to this.state.title

Comment: For 2 reasons. 1. The push() method adds elements to the end of an array. `this.state.title` is a string. 2. To change a state, do like you did one line below : `this.setState({ title: this.state.title });` or, because they have the same name, you can do it shorter : `this.setState({ title });`. You can combine the both : `this.setState({ title, post: this.state.title });`

Comment: OK. I got it:
    this.addPost = this.addPost.bind(this);
  }
    addPost(title){
      this.setState({ title });
  }
THANKS! :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind `handleAddNew` to `this` in the same way you did for `this.updateNewPost`!